# Installed package disappear on Google Cloud VMS instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

so I have installed some python nltk libraries (pip3 install) and c++ libraries (via apt-get install package_name_xxxx) on two different VMS instances.

Python packages for nltk would disappear and require a reinstall after reboot or change of the vms instance (e.g., add memory, cpu core),

C++ libraries disappeared without rebooting or any change of the machine. I do not find anything in the systemlog, a reinstall with apt-get works fine. But I am trying to figure out why it happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installed packages disappeared in Google Cloud Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784845/installed-packages-disappeared-in-google-cloud-shell)

Comment: no, it seems to be a different issue.

Comment: what type of disk are you using with your VM? If you are using Local SSD, you may want to try different one: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/

Comment: Is there some form of an auto delete or deep freeze that you may have enabled . (Sorry I'm a GCE beginner)

Answer (score 0):

Is your GCE instance a [preemptible](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) instance? this option restarts the instance once every 24 hours and could be the reason why you are missing some packages.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the option is off for Preemptibility Off.

Answer (score -3):

After about an hour of inactivity, modifications not within the `$HOME` directory are lost. This includes installed packages.
See [Custom installed software packages and persistence](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#custom_installed_software_packages_and_persistence) and [usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I googled that first but seems not the case because I have installed other tools/pakages outside of the $HOME (e.g., supervisor) and did not have this issue.

Comment: His issue is with a Compute Engine instance, not with the Google Cloud Shell.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the option is off for Preemptibility 
Off.